# Using the filename of workbook to find image with same filename Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I was testing importing an image into a worksheet, which has proved successful, how can I use the filename of my workbook, which I store in a range to then look in a preselected directory for the image with the same filename?

My filename is held in Range - LkupFileName

```
Sub InsertImage()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ImgPath As String
    Dim W As Double, H As Double
    Dim L As Long, T As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myworksheet")
    '~~> File Location of saved JPG
    ImgPath = "C:\images.jpg"
    With ws
       W = 100  '<~~ Width
       H = 50   '<~~ Height
       L = .Range("H140").Left   '<~~ Left Position for image
       T = .Range("H140").Top    '<~~ Top Position for image
       'Copy & Paste Image code
       With .Pictures.Insert(ImgPath)
          With .ShapeRange
             .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
             .Width = W
             .Height = H
          End With
          .Left = L
          .Top = T
          .Placement = 1
       End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If I got this right, the range holding your filename is named `LkupFileName` and it's the exact same name of your image?

Comment: yes, i hold the filename within the range LkupFilename and that will be the same as the image name

Comment: Thanks. If we are on the same page and it's indeed a named range, see my answer below and test if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub InsertImage()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ImgPath As String, ImgName As String
    Dim W As Double, H As Double
    Dim L As Long, T As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myworksheet")
    '~~> File Location of saved JPG
    ImgName = ws.Range("LkupFileName").Value
    ImgPath = "C:\Foo\Bar\" & ImgName & ".jpg" 'Modify accordingly.
    With ws
       W = 100  '<~~ Width
       H = 50   '<~~ Height
       L = .Range("H140").Left   '<~~ Left Position for image
       T = .Range("H140").Top    '<~~ Top Position for image
       'Copy & Paste Image code
       With .Pictures.Insert(ImgPath)
          With .ShapeRange
             .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
             .Width = W
             .Height = H
          End With
          .Left = L
          .Top = T
          .Placement = 1
       End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Two things are assumed:

- By `LkupFileName`, I'm assuming this is a named range.
- The image will always be found in the directory you specify.

Let us know if this helps. :)

Comment: @Jez: If this was helpful to you, kindly mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark on the upper left side of this post. This is how we say thanks in SO. :)

Comment: apologies, just seen your post. Thanks for your help